# ListView.setAdapter(android.widget.ListAdapter)' on a null object reference in android

Tags: android, listview, nullpointerexception

Hi in the below where click on this fragment my list view getting null pointer. 
If it is normal activity it is working fine.it is crashing my app

can any one please help me where i did the mistake.

```
public class HomeFragement extends Fragment {

    EditText et_building;
    TextView Add;
    ListView lv;
    ArrayList<String> arrayList;
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;



    public HomeFragement() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        ((NavigationViewActivity) getActivity()).setActionBarTitle("ADD BUILDING");

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_building, container, false);

        init();

        return rootView;
    }

    private void clickListener() {
        Add.setOnClickListener (new View.OnClickListener ( ) {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String result=et_building.getText ().toString ();
                arrayList.add (result);
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged ();

            }
        });
    }

    private void init() {
        et_building=(EditText)getActivity ().findViewById (R.id.build_name);
        Add=(TextView)getActivity ().findViewById (R.id.addbuild);
        lv=(ListView)getActivity ().findViewById (R.id.list_building);
        arrayList=new ArrayList<String> ();
        adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String> (getActivity (),android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,arrayList);
        lv.setAdapter(adapter);
        clickListener();
    }
```

Comment: Is the listview in your fragment or your activity?

Comment: In Fragment......

Comment: check my answer and implement it

Comment: say rootView.findViewById and not getActivity()

Answer (score 0):

> **Problem found - Issue in declaring id. use `rootView` instead of `getActivity()`**

Do this

```
    init(rootView);
```

And this method should be

```
private void init(View rootView ) {
        et_building=(EditText)rootView.findViewById (R.id.build_name);
        Add=(TextView)rootView.findViewById (R.id.addbuild);
        lv=(ListView)rootView.findViewById (R.id.list_building);
        arrayList=new ArrayList<String> ();
        adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String> (getActivity (),android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,arrayList);
        lv.setAdapter(adapter);
        clickListener();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to put this your `init()` code inside `onCreateView()` like:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    ((NavigationViewActivity) getActivity()).setActionBarTitle("ADD BUILDING");

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_building, container, false);

    et_building=(EditText)rootView.findViewById (R.id.build_name);
    Add=(TextView)rootView.findViewById (R.id.addbuild);
    lv=(ListView)rootView.findViewById (R.id.list_building);
    arrayList=new ArrayList<String> ();
    adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String> (getActivity(),android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,arrayList);
    lv.setAdapter(adapter);

    return rootView;
}
```

and use `rootView` instead of `getActivity()` to creating new object